Ubuntu locale settings not reflected in environment variables
My Ubuntu machine (24.04) should use the en_US.UTF-8 locale, but somehow, it is not reflected in the actual locale output:
user@machine:~$ locale -a
C
C.utf8
POSIX
en_US.utf8
user@machine:~$ localectl status
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: (unset)         
   X11 Layout: de
    X11 Model: pc105
user@machine:~$ cat /etc/default/locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
user@machine:~$ locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=

Why are the environment variables not aligned with the settings?

I issue is related to my sshd configuration (UsePAM no), I found the answer here.
